# Can I use v-if and v-for outside HTML tag?

Tags: vue.js

The point is that if the condition is satisfied I should assign whole list to a variable, otherwise I need to iterate through list and assign element by element.

```
<ul>
 <li v-if="flag = true">
  <myVueComponent                            
   v-bind:list="LIST">
  </myVueComponent>
 <v-else v-for="item in LIST">
  <a v-else :href="url+item.name">@{{item.name}}</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

If this is not valid code, then could I use `v-if` inside one `<li>` tag and `v-else` inside another `<li>` tag? In that case I would also use `v-for` in that tag.

Comment: maybe you want to use v-if on <ul>?

Comment: I can't do that, I need either one of these two to show. So if I use `v-if` inside `<ul>` then in case when condition is not satisfied, I wouldn't have `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, yes, you could use it inside `v-if` inside one list element and `v-else` inside another:

```
<ul>
 <li v-if="flag">
  <myVueComponent                            
   v-bind:list="LIST">
  </myVueComponent>
 </li>
 <li v-else v-for="item in LIST">
  <a :href="url+item.name">@{{item.name}}</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `v-if="flag === true` or simply `v-if="flag"`?

Comment: @wwerner my bad, quicktyping, wasn't paying attention. Thank you